# turning grammar to LL(1)

Tags: grammar, ambiguous, ll-grammar

can somebody please help me turn the following grammar to LL(1),
and explain how he did it please?

```
B → B and B | not B | ( B ) | id
```

i need the not operator to have precedence over the and operator.
thank you!
edit:
my results so far:

```
B - > Eb'
B' -> andBE'
B" -> epslion (empty)
E -> E'F
E' -> notE'F
E' -> epsilon (empty)
F -> id
F -> (B)
F -> B
```

Comment: Assuming this is a context-free grammar, try converting to [Greibach Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greibach_normal_form), where the right hand side for the non-terminals (B) all start with different terminals.  Hint: you may need to introduce new non-terminals.  There are plenty of class notes on the internet that describe how to do this step-by-step.

Comment: thank you for your answer. i have tried all of those for quite some time, yet i failed. i will add my result

Comment: You're making it more difficult than it needs to be.  Start with your alphabet of terminals `{and, not, (, ), id}`.  For GNF, the right hand side of each production rule must start with one and only one of these, followed by zero or more non-terminal symbols.  Don't worry about epsilon, you don't need it.  And don't worry about the operator precedence until you've sorted the basic GNF.